# Javascript indexOf or Contains

Tags: javascript

I would like to validate a field with the following condition: Password should not contain any words in the email.

e.g. email: tryemail@yahoo.com

So password must not contain tryemail word.

With this code, I achieve it:

```
var emailSubstring = email.substr(0, email.indexOf("@"));
if (password.indexOf(emailSubstring) != -1)
{
    // do something here //
}
```

My problem is this: When I enter the word `try` on the password field, it is not validating it. Unless I make it `tryemail`.

Is there any possible way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Note: This is not a password requirements policy issue. I appreciate your opinion about why should I validate password. My answer would be business requirements. Thanks!

Comment: "Password should not contain any words in the email", you will need some kind of logic to determine what you consider an `word`. Then test it against all words.

Comment: your rule will break on the legal address `"foo@bar"@example.com`

Comment: The password must not contain a substring or the whole string itself from the email? Just for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the opposite:

```
if (emailSubstring.indexOf(password) != -1)
```

Some bulletproof code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QxmYV/1/

Comment: It is behaving the same way.